# Monkey Patching to Add Functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, class, monkeypatching

In python, I have some string utility functions I commonly use. These include extensions of built-in methods (such as a split function that supports both normal strings and regex), helper functions for built-in methods (such as a strip function that has parameters for what to strip, instead of the three built-in functions), and brand new functionality.

I currently have them in the form of independent functions, like this:

```
function strip(s, left: bool = True, right: bool = True):
if left and right:
    return s.strip()
elif left:
    return s.lstrip()
elif right:
    return s.rstrip()
else:
    return s
```

However, this isn't very convenient. Built-in methods are members of the `str` class, so they are called with the dot operator. `mystring.strip()` is more concise and convenient than `strip(mystring)`. In addition, the former is consistent with built-in methods.

To solve this problem, I want to use monkey patching. Monkey patching is where you add your own method to a class from outside the class:

```
str.mystrip = strip
```

This allows the new function to be called in the form of `mystring.mystrip()`.

However, monkey patching is generally considered bad practice.

So, is it okay to monkey patch the `str` class with my custom functions? Or is this bad practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: In my opinion, if you work with other developers, it is a bad practice. otherwise, you can do what you want to do. Especially, you must remember that you had overwrite the `str` class after several months.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the other way is more concise (one less period!)

That aside, the best would probably be to subclass the str class instead.
You get all the functionality of str plus whatever new functionality you'd like to add. You can see some information on that here: https://realpython.com/inherit-python-str/#extending-the-strings-standard-behavior

One of their examples is:

```
class WordCountString(str):
    def words(self, separator=None):
        return len(self.split(separator))
```

You can see that WordCountString inherits str. Then they define a new function to be used with the new type.